# use regex inside puppet file resource

Tags: puppet

I want to delete a file using file resource. File name is AA_BB_CC_11.22.33.7z . Problem is file resource does not support regex and the numbers in the can be changed. I am using variable inside my manifest to store filename as $app=AA_BB_CC_*.7z

The exec resource is able to download the file from central server but file resource is not able to delete it. I came to know another resource tidy to delete file but that resource is executing before other resource even if i have mentioned resource sequence. How can i implement this to delete this file?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you can write a *find* command to list all of your files that you want deleted.
Let's also assume that you're puppet module knows *when* do delete these files.
Unix:
`exec { 'delete_files':
  command  => "/bin/find [your find command arguments here] -delete",
}`
Some find commands don't have -delete, so that would be
`"/bin/find [your find command arguments here] -exec rm -f {} \;"`

Windows:
Been a Loooong time since I've done Windows, a CMD might be something like this:
`dir [path] [file_wildcard] | find "[string of correct characters]"`
Can't remember how to send this output to the ERASE command. Powershell was invented after I quit Windows, so that may have a way.